# FreeBSD - How can I let server A get web access via server B over a specific port?

Tags: proxy, port-forwarding, freebsd

**Setup:**

- Server A: FreeBSD 10 - IP: 100.100.100.100
- Server B: FreeBSD 9  - IP: 200.200.200.200

Both servers use pf.conf.

**Desired result:**

I want server A to be able to get web access (port 80) via server B over a specific port (ex: 3333). How would one accomplish that in the easiest possible way? Is it possible to do this by just changing pf.conf on server B?

Any hands on examples will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you want an IP masquerading NAT. Well, luckily there is a document on [port forwarding](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/rdr.html) which can hopefully aid you in your quest.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution was to install tinyproxy:  `pkg install www/tinyproxy`.

After that I made sure that the firewall on Server B was open to incoming connections on port 3333 from Server A and changed the default port in the tinyproxy config to 3333.